# Understanding recursive odd/even functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm currently studying python from http://www.sololearn.com/Play/Python and I'm having trouble understanding why this code works.

```
def is_even(x):
    if x == 0:
        return True

    else:
        return is_odd(x-1)

def is_odd(x):
    return not is_even(x)

print(is_odd(1))
```

I get how recursion works for a fibonacci and factorial but I can't wrap my head around this one.

Comment: What exactly don't you understand? On a side note, please don't write code like this, it is hell.

Comment: I just had a little trouble evaluating the code in my head, I get it now.
I realize this code is really bad though since it takes up too much power for something that can be done using the % operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is_even'`s base case resolves to `True`. Since `is_odd(x)` returns `not is_even(x)`, the value `True` will be a part of the expression returned by `is_odd`. The question is how many times will that `True` value be *negated*. By tracing the calls you can see it will be negated an even number of times, and hence "retain" its truthiness, when `x` is odd [e.g.: `x=3` ==> `(not (not (not (not True))))` == `True`] and an odd number of times, and hence "lose" its truthiness, when `x` is even [e.g.: `x=2` ==> `(not (not (not True)))` == `False`]. There's probably some term from logic that names this general property of multiple negation.

Comment: "Double-negation elimination"

Answer (score 2):

It's based on an inductive definition of evenness:

- Zero is even
- If some number "n" is even, then "n+1" is not even
- If some number "n" is not even, then "n+1" is even

"odd" is obviously "not even".

The code takes this definition, and checks it backwards - using recursion.

- If i have zero, then it is even
- If I have some other number "n" , then it is even if "n-1" is not - that is, if "n-1" is odd.

Answer (score 0):

That recursive function is really a bad way to teach recursion, you should apply recursion only when it's useful. In fact, test those functions with negative numbers and you'll get `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` errors.

To check parity numbers you'd better use `%` operator or `&` and operator, ie:

```
def is_even(x):
    return (x & 1) == 0


def is_odd(x):
    return (x & 1) == 1
```

That said, I think @Elazar & @DAXaholic answers should give you some insights about that buggy recursive function and wrap your mind about it.

Comment: Parity checks are computationally efficient, but they exploit the representation. The recursion is the straight-forward definition in this case, even if not efficient.

Comment: And yes, it is only defined on natural numbers. That's ok and can easily be extended

Comment: @Elazar What do you mean by straight-forward definition? The most basic definition of parity is about defining just a couple of sets. For instance: let n be an integer, even = {2n} and odd = {2n+1} , that's pretty much, you don't need to derive the original definition into a recursive function... IMHO doesn't produce any real benefit (not even for learning)

Comment: @BPL That's not the most basic definition; it requires definitions of multiplication and addition. At its most basic, a natural number is either `Zero` or `Succ(n)` for some other natural number `n`.  The definition does not include any operations at all; they are all *derived* from `Zero` and `Succ`. Specifically, the mutually recursive definitions of `even` and `odd` don't rely on definitions of arithmetic; they can be rewritten more properly as `even(Zero) = True`, `odd(Zero) = False`, `even(Succ(n)) = odd(n)`, and `odd(Succ(n)) = even(n)`.

Comment: @BPL It does, for learning, and the definition you've mentioned is not what you teach kids, and not what you will define in e.g. the COQ proof assistant.

Comment: @chepner `Parity is a mathematical term that describes the property of an integer's inclusion in one of two categories: even or odd. An integer is even if it is 'evenly divisible' by two and odd if it is not even.` It seems your definition only works with natural numbers (N), not integer ones (Z).

Comment: The OP's definition of `even` and `odd` are only defined  (or I should say, guarantee termination) for natural numbers; I'm not addressing integers here.

Answer (score 0):

A little hint:

```
0 -> True
1 -> not True
2 -> not not True
3 -> not not not True
...
```

and so on.